# How to avoid type chaning on last element when removing elements from python lists

Tags: python, list, types

Wrote a program to return all permutations of a string.  Tried to apply the same logic to a list permutation.  I get a type error on the last element because python is changing the type of lst to a string which no longer has the pop method. Is there a way to avoid this?

```py
def permutestring(string, newstr="", array=[]):
    if len(string) == 0:
        array.append(newstr)
    for char in string:
        permutestring(string.replace(char, "", 1), newstr + char, array)
    return array

print(permutestring("test"))
```

```py
def permutelist(lst, newlst=[], array=[]):
    if not lst:
        array.append(newlst)
     for item in lst:
        permutelist(lst.pop(lst.index(item)), newlst+[item], array)
    return array
print(permutelist(["apples", "pears", "oranges", "kiwis"]))
```

The first runs fine and returns an array of all permutations.  The second throws AttributeError on trying to pop from str object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because according to [[Python 3.Docs]: Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures) (**emphasis** is mine)

> list.**pop**(*[i]*)
>
> Remove the item at the given position in the list, **and return it**.

So, the 1<sup>st</sup> *pop* will return a string which will be passed to the next (recurring) *permutelist* call, which will (obviously) fail. 
To fix things, instead of `lst.pop(lst.index(item))`, construct a new list that contains the elements before the current index, plus the ones after it (meaning that it will be left out). Also notice the use of [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Functions - **enumerate**(*iterable, start=0*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to avoid getting each element's index.

> ```
> >>> from pprint import pprint
> >>>
> >>> def permutelist(lst, newlst=[], array=[]):
> ...     if not lst:
> ...         array.append(newlst)
> ...     for idx, item in enumerate(lst):
> ...         permutelist(lst[:idx] + lst[idx + 1:], newlst + [item], array)
> ...     return array
> ...
> >>> pprint(permutelist(["apples", "pears", "oranges", "kiwis"]))
> [['apples', 'pears', 'oranges', 'kiwis'],
>  ['apples', 'pears', 'kiwis', 'oranges'],
>  ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'kiwis'],
>  ['apples', 'oranges', 'kiwis', 'pears'],
>  ['apples', 'kiwis', 'pears', 'oranges'],
>  ['apples', 'kiwis', 'oranges', 'pears'],
>  ['pears', 'apples', 'oranges', 'kiwis'],
>  ['pears', 'apples', 'kiwis', 'oranges'],
>  ['pears', 'oranges', 'apples', 'kiwis'],
>  ['pears', 'oranges', 'kiwis', 'apples'],
>  ['pears', 'kiwis', 'apples', 'oranges'],
>  ['pears', 'kiwis', 'oranges', 'apples'],
>  ['oranges', 'apples', 'pears', 'kiwis'],
>  ['oranges', 'apples', 'kiwis', 'pears'],
>  ['oranges', 'pears', 'apples', 'kiwis'],
>  ['oranges', 'pears', 'kiwis', 'apples'],
>  ['oranges', 'kiwis', 'apples', 'pears'],
>  ['oranges', 'kiwis', 'pears', 'apples'],
>  ['kiwis', 'apples', 'pears', 'oranges'],
>  ['kiwis', 'apples', 'oranges', 'pears'],
>  ['kiwis', 'pears', 'apples', 'oranges'],
>  ['kiwis', 'pears', 'oranges', 'apples'],
>  ['kiwis', 'oranges', 'apples', 'pears'],
>  ['kiwis', 'oranges', 'pears', 'apples']]
> ```

Or, **it would make much more sense** to use [[Python 3.Docs]: itertools.**permutations**(*iterable, r=None*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) which does the same thing (most likely, faster and better).

> ```
> >>> pprint(list(itertools.permutations(["apples", "pears", "oranges", "kiwis"])))
> [('apples', 'pears', 'oranges', 'kiwis'),
>  ('apples', 'pears', 'kiwis', 'oranges'),
>  ('apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'kiwis'),
>  ('apples', 'oranges', 'kiwis', 'pears'),
>  ('apples', 'kiwis', 'pears', 'oranges'),
>  ('apples', 'kiwis', 'oranges', 'pears'),
>  ('pears', 'apples', 'oranges', 'kiwis'),
>  ('pears', 'apples', 'kiwis', 'oranges'),
>  ('pears', 'oranges', 'apples', 'kiwis'),
>  ('pears', 'oranges', 'kiwis', 'apples'),
>  ('pears', 'kiwis', 'apples', 'oranges'),
>  ('pears', 'kiwis', 'oranges', 'apples'),
>  ('oranges', 'apples', 'pears', 'kiwis'),
>  ('oranges', 'apples', 'kiwis', 'pears'),
>  ('oranges', 'pears', 'apples', 'kiwis'),
>  ('oranges', 'pears', 'kiwis', 'apples'),
>  ('oranges', 'kiwis', 'apples', 'pears'),
>  ('oranges', 'kiwis', 'pears', 'apples'),
>  ('kiwis', 'apples', 'pears', 'oranges'),
>  ('kiwis', 'apples', 'oranges', 'pears'),
>  ('kiwis', 'pears', 'apples', 'oranges'),
>  ('kiwis', 'pears', 'oranges', 'apples'),
>  ('kiwis', 'oranges', 'apples', 'pears'),
>  ('kiwis', 'oranges', 'pears', 'apples')]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

if you cast explicitly does it fix the problem ?

```
list(array)
```

otherwise you can try/catch this exception

```
def permutelist(lst, newlst=[], array=[]):  
     for item in lst:
         try :
             permutelist(lst.pop(lst.index(item)), newlst+[item], array)
         except AttributeError:         
             array.append(newlst)
    return array
print(permutelist(["apples", "pears", "oranges", "kiwis"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

lst.pop() will return the given value for the index that it removes. In your case, this is a string. To avoid this, simply wrap the string at the index in a new list and call your function on the new list:

```
def permutelist(lst, newlst=[], array=[]):
    print(lst)
    print(type(lst))
    if not lst:
        array.append(newlst)
    for item in lst:
        new_list = []
        new_list.append(new_list.append(lst.pop(lst.index(item))))
        permutelist(new_list, newlst+[item], array)
    return array
print(permutelist(["apples", "pears", "oranges", "kiwis"]))
```